Is there a command to add gem to gemspec?
I know there is a command to add a gem to Gemfile: bundle add GEMNAME, but is there a similar command to add a dependency to gemspec?
Is there something like bundle add rails --gemspec?
Is there a command that adds this line to gemspec?:
  spec.add_dependency 'GEMNAME', 'GEMVERSION'


Unless it's a development-only dependency, what do you imagine the syntax difference actually is? Have you read the Bundler docs on the subject?

Bundler adds gem to Gemfile (development) not to gemspec, and I want to add non-development gems to gemspec with a command.

The answer to my knowledge is No. Nothing shows up in the CLI Docs for the gem command and the bundler Docs are pretty clear about how to add a dependency. Not sure why a CLI command would be useful when it seems like it would be just as easy to type that line into the gemspec

The syntax differences are minimal. You can copy-and-paste lines from your Gemfile to your .gemspec and then call s/^gem/ spec.add_dependency/ or use spec.add_development_dependency instead if it's a dev-only dependency. It's trivial to do with vim or sed, which is probably why there's no CLI support for it.

I think the answer is "no". At least, not with the "standard" ruby tools; someone out there might have built a CLI for it, but I can't find one.

I've barely ever used the bundle add command. For most use cases I expect it's only marginally faster than editing the Gemfile and running bundle, with the added downside that you need to remember this special command (and probably still check that it made the right change in the Gemfile!).
Maybe it would be useful if I was adding the same dependency to a dozen projects or something, but that's not a "normal" task for me to do.
Likewise, I can't really imagine a scenario where using a CLI to update a gemspec is really beneficial. Surely it's equally fast, if not faster, to just open the gemspec and edit it directly?
That's why there's (as far as I can find?) no popular tool for automating this.

On a side note, the command bundle gem <gemname> is very useful, when creating a new gem, because it automates a lot of boilerplate code to kickstart a new library, similar to running rails new <app-name>.

TL;DR
Your question pre-supposes that a Gem::Specification stored in a .gemspec file needs to contain the same level of dependency information as a Gemfile parsed by Bundler. This generally isn't the case, and is likely the reason the support you want isn't there.
You are correct that there isn't currently such support. However, I provide examples of porting a minimal set of dependencies from a Gemfile into your Gem::Specification, and some food for thought about how and why to keep as much dependency management in your Gemfile as is reasonable for your particular package or library.
CLI Changes to a .gemspec File Aren't Supported
I didn't see a CLI option similar to bundle-add in the RubyGems command reference site for adding lines directly to a .gemspec file from the command line, but the syntax for gems in a gemspec is quite similar unless you're using some of the more advanced syntax from Bundler.
However, the differences for the simplest cases are trivial, which is probably why they aren't supported. I provide some examples of how to convert them with sed or a text editor below.
In addition, any gem that is likely to be included as a library rather than as an executable may not technically need to specific runtime dependencies. It may be sufficient (if not necessarily best practice) to incude only development dependencies in your .gemspec, and leave the rest to Bundler and the Gemfile.
Gemfile vs. Gem::Specification
A .gemspec is really intended to be informational, but can be used to build gems without Bundler if you don't need Bundler's advanced features. Bundler can also include a .gemspec in its Gemfile for use during dependency resolution, but the reverse is not true.
The main difference in specifications is that a Bundler Gemfile supports a lot more features (e.g. grouping) and can make use of more advanced specifications than a .gemspec file. Some examples of this is defining non-standard require statements within a Gemfile, or using Install_if; these are things Bundler can do handle but a standard .gemspec cannot.
For simpler use cases, though, the specification syntax between the two file formats are fairly equivalent and you can use sed or a text editor to make the minor changes needed to port files from your Gemfile into your Gem::Specification.
Example of Converting Gemfile Specifications to Gem::Specification
For uncomplicated cases, you can do something like this:

Copy-and-paste lines from your Gemfile to your .gemspec.
Change the Bundler gem line to fit Gem::Specification syntax.

In vim: :%s/^gem/spec.add_dependency/ for general dependencies.

You can do the same from the command line with GNU sed:
# for items in your global group
sed -ri "s/^gem/spec.add_dependency/" .gemspec

# for items your Gemfile's development group
sed -ri "s/^gem/spec.add_development_dependency/" .gemspec

# for items in your various runtime groups
sed -ri "s/^gem/spec.add_runtime_dependency/" .gemspec

Note: #add_dependency is pragmatically synonymous with #add_runtime_dependency, but is more intention-revealing. You can use either one, depending on your semantic intent but it makes no different to Bundler.




Because a gem typically defines it own require statements in gem_name/lib/gem_name.rb the lack of sophistication in the .gemspec file is rarely a real-world problem. In such cases, listing your development dependencies in the Gem::Specification and then relying on your Gemfile or Gemfile.lock (there has been debate about including or excluding Gemfile.lock from libraries, but most people nowadays seem to include it) then you can treat the .gemspec as informational and let Bundler manage the actual dependencies, groups, conditionals, and other fancy stuff prior to building and pushing the gem.
Examples
In my personal experience, keeping .gemspec specifications as simple as possible is usually best because Bundler is such a common part of the ecosystem and is much more powerful. Best practice or not, I often build libraries where my minimal expectations are defined in the :
# foo.gemspec
spec.add_dependency "bundler"
spec.add_development_dependency "standardrb"

# Gemfile
gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem "standard", "~> 1.36"
end

In this example, I inform RubyGems that some version of Bundler is a core dependency and that Standardrb (a meta-gem for the Standard gem) will be required for development. I could specify a constraint on Bundler if I need to, but I usually don't especially in libraries, and standardrb doesn't really need one because I'll add any necessary constraints on the Standard gem or other specific dependencies within the Gemfile instead.
Meanwhile, in the Gemfile the gemspec method pulls in Standardrb and its dependencies, while the :development and :test groups both include the standard gem itself and its dependencies. I do this because Gem::Specification#add_development_dependency only assigns to a single group (usually :development, but configurable within Bundler) whereas Bundler itself can add items to multiple groups or a list of groups.
The specification for Standard within the group constrains Standard to the minor semantic version I've defined (e.g. 1.36). The Bundler resolver then handles the dependencies for that specific version of Standard, too!
It's generally much nicer to do this sort of thing in Bundler than in a Gem::Specification, but your mileage and use case may vary. However, it's a reasonable pattern that not only solves your issue by trimming the fat in your .gemspec file and making it easy to define the minimum necessary metadata about your gem's dependencies, but also puts the full power of Bundler at your disposal at the optional cost of having a Gem::Specification that is less than exact.
A Popular Gem in the Wild
To drive this all home, note that you will find a lot of gems on the main RubyGems repository that have Gem::Specification versions listed as >=0 or that just list their runtime or development dependencies. For example, RSpec 3.13.0 lists only three runtime dependencies:
rspec-core ~> 3.13.0
rspec-expectations ~> 3.13.0
rspec-mocks ~> 3.13.0

and a required Ruby version of >= 0. This may or may not be ideal, but listing only runtime or development dependencies in a Gem::Specification is surprisingly common. Other than for metadata about the gem itself, Bundler offers more configuration options and arguably more powerful dependency resolution capabilities, so it often pays to specify as little about gem dependencies as truly necessary within your Gem::Specification and leave the rest to Bundler's Gemfile.
